# Polynomial with a root that occurs n times, the root must be 0

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I'm having a bit trouble with this excercise:

**The problem:**
Let there be a polynomial $f(x)=a_1x^{t_1} + a_2x^{t_2} + ... + a_nx^{t_n}$
Where $t_1, t_2, ..., t_n$ are not-negative integers.
The polynomial has a root $b$ which occurs $n$ times.
Prove that $b = 0$.

**What I have so far:**
I can presume that $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n \neq 0$
If $n = 1$, then it's obviously true.
If $n = 2$, I tried using this:
$f^{(n-1)}(b) = 0
\\
f^{(n)}(b) = 0$
So:
$f(b) = a_1b^{t_1} + a_2b^{t_2} = 0
\\
f'(b) = t_1*a_1b^{(t_1-1)} + t_2*a_2b^{(t_2-1)} = 0
\\
f''(b) = (t_1-1)t_1*a_1b^{(t_1-2)} + (t_2-1)t_2*a_2b^{(t_2-2)} \neq 0$
Why can't $b \neq 0$ be true?

Comment: So, you presume your polynomial $f(x)$ factors as $(x-b)^n r(x)$, where $r(x)$ is another polynomial. Have you tried comparing coefficients?

Comment: My first instinct would be to assume (without loss of generality) that $t_1\le t_2\le\cdots\le t_n$ and factor out $x^{t_1}$.

Comment: Have you counted the number of non-zero coefficients in $(x-b)^n$ when b is not zero and compared it to your number of coefficients?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. $(x-b)^n$ has $n+1$ number of coefficients (binomial theorem). f(x) has $n$. But how can I prove that $(x-b)^nr(x)$ still has $n+1$ coefficients?

Comment: @user30620: $(x-b)^n$ has $n+1$ terms if and only if $b\neq0$...

Answer (score 3):

You have $b^kf^{(k)}(b)=0$ for $k=0,\dots,n-1$, i.e. $\sum_{j}p_i(t_j)b^{t_j}a_j=0$, where $p_i(x)=x(x-1)\dots(x-i+1)$. If $b^{t_j}a_j\neq 0$ for at least one $j$ then there are some $c_0,\dots,c_{n-1}$, not all zero, such that $\sum_i c_ip_i(t_j)=0$ for all $j$'s (that's where linear algebra is used). But the polynomial $\sum_i c_ip_i(x)$ has degree at most $n-1$, so it can't have $n$ different roots.

Comment: Could you explain "If $b^{t_j}a_j\neq 0$ for at least one j then there are some c0,…,cn−1, not all zero, such that $\sum_i c_ip_i(t_j)=0$ for all j's (that's where linear algebra is used)" a bit further?

Comment: @user30620: if $M$ is a square matrix and $Mu=0$ for some non-zero vector (column) $u$ then there is a non-zero (row) vector $v$ s.t. $vM=0$ (as row rank = column rank). In our case the entries of $M$ are $p_i(t_j)$.

Comment: Are $u$ and $v$ taken from the matrix $M$? Also are you implying that $\sum_i c_ip_i(x)$ is equal to $f(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

We can also do this by induction on $n$. If $n=1$, then $x=0$ is the only root, and there is nothing to prove.

The key is that if $b\neq0$ is a root of $f(x)$ with multiplicity $\ge n$, then it is a root of $f'(x)$ with multiplicity $\ge n-1$. Consequently it is also a root of multiplicity $\ge n-1$ of the combination
$$
g(x):=f(x)-\frac1{t_n} xf'(x).
$$
But the highest degree term disappears from $g(x)$, in other words
$$
g(x)=b_1x^{t_1}+b_2x^{t_2}+\cdots+b_{n-1}x^{t_{n-1}},
$$
with the coefficients $b_j$ all non-zero (assuming that $a_j\neq0$ for all $j$. After all, we have
$$
b_j=a_j\left(1-\frac{t_j}{t_n}\right)
$$
for all $j$.
By the induction hypothesis (applied to $g(x)$) this is impossible, so we have a contradiction, and the induction is complete.