# Prove that in $a_1 x^{n_1} + a_2 x^{n_2} + \dots + a_k x^{n_k}$, $n_1 < n_2 < \dots < n_k$, each non-zero root has multiplicity not above $k-1$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, roots

Prove that in the polynomial $a_1 x^{n_1} + a_2 x^{n_2} + \dots + a_k x^{n_k}$, where $n_1 < n_2 < \dots < n_k$, each non-zero root has multiplicity not above $k-1$.

As I understand it, this can be proven by induction, taking $k=2$
as a base and assuming that $x^{n−1} \ne 0$, we get the expression $\dfrac{a_1}{a_2}+x^{n_2−n_1}=0$, since the number of roots of a polynomial of degree $n_2−n_1$ does not exceed $n_2−n_1$  even if multiple roots are counted taking into account the multiplicity. But I couldn’t figure out how to prove the induction transition.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Dominique As I understand it, this can be proven by induction, taking $ k = 2 $ as a base and assuming that $ x^{n -1} \neq 0 $, we get the expression $ \frac{a1}{a2} + x^{n_2-n_1} = 0 $, since the number of roots of a polynomial of degree $ n_2-n_1 $ does not exceed
$ n_2-n_1 $ even if multiple roots are counted taking into account the multiplicity. But I couldn’t figure out how to prove the induction transition

Comment: A special case is in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1875134/242). As I mention there this is a special case of Khovanskii's work on fewmonomials.

Comment: @АндрейС.: I've updated your question, adding your efforts and I've asked to reopen your question. General advise: add your effort to your question, otherwise people might be tempted to close your question.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this older question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/140870/11619).

Comment: I answered what I think this is a duplicate of. That question isn't very good either, but it is older. Will happily relocate my answer (or delete it), if judged prudent. No deep theory, just the observation that the exact same terms (save for the one with the highest degree) appear in $f(x)-(x/n_k)f'(x)$.